# What happens under the hood when you pass a string to a function in C

Tags: c, string

Does the compiler convert it to a string literal?

Is there any difference between these two?

```
printf("Hello world\n");
```

and

```
char* c = "Hello world\n";
printf(c); //I know you shouldn't do this
```

Comment: I recommend putting both samples of code into [Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) to see if the compiler generates the same assembly.  I think most of them will generate different assembly, because the code is different.

Comment: @Gerhardh The first snippet passes one argument to printf and the second one passes two arguments, lol.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you are right. I was focused on the `hello world` part.

Comment: The compiler does not convert any string into a string literal. In your code the `"hello world\n"` string is passed by providing its address to `printf`. In both cases they already *are* string literals. Only difference is that in first code the string is passed as fixed argument `(char* fmt, ...` while in second snippet it is passed as a variable argument (see the `, ...)` part of `printf`).

Comment: Under the hood, `printf` *always* receives a pointer.  Always.  What's hard to understand at first is that any time you think you're passing or otherwise doing something with an array, what you're really working with is the automatically-generated pointer to the array's first element, i.e. the "array to pointer decay" discussed in Dúthomhas's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A *string* is just an array of `char` (where content is terminated by the presence of a nul character).

```
char s[] = "Hi";                // These two declarations
char s[] = { 'H', 'i', '\0' };  // are equivalent
```

Arrays are not first class citizens in C. They cannot be passed to or returned from functions.

*Pointers*, on the other hand, are scalar types and can be passed to and returned from functions just as any other scalar type: by value. That is, the value of the pointer (the memory address it holds) is passed to or returned from a function.

So when you type:

```
puts( "Hello world" );
```

what happens is that the *address* of the first character of the literal array is passed to the function.

As you suspect, this is no different than:

```
const char * s = "Hello world";  // s is a pointer to read-only memory
puts( s );
```

Again, `s` is a pointer containing the address of the first character in the literal array. Its value (the address) is passed to the function.

If `s` were an array:

```
char s[] = "Hello world";  // s is an array, content copied from read-only memory
puts( s );
```

then the address of the first element of the array would be passed to the function.

You find this same thing true of any kind of array in C:

```
int xs[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };
some_function( xs );
```

The array itself is not passed to the function, but the *value of the pointer `&(xs[0])` is passed*, where the value is the address of the first element of the array.

In C we call this “array-to-pointer decay”.

(An array is an address, element type, and count of elements. A pointer is just an address and element type.)

Comment: you should point out that `char *x  = "foo"` and `char[] ="Foo"` do entirely different things

Comment: Alas, trying to keep this as simple as possible without digging up too many worms... If you wish to phrase some part better please feel free to either suggest or give an edit.